# Filter via different dates in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Here I've created a simple table using MS SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Students1 (
FirstName Nvarchar(100),
SecondName Nvarchar(100),
DOB Smalldatetime,
RegisterDate smalldatetime,
Archived int,
ArchivedDate Smalldatetime
);

Insert Into Students1(FirstName,SecondNAme,DOB,RegisterDate,Archived,ArchivedDate)
Values('James','Bike',16/04/1900, 04/07/2017,0,Null);
Insert Into Students1(FirstName,SecondNAme,DOB,RegisterDate,Archived,ArchivedDate)
Values('Adam','Bike',16/04/1901,04/07/2017,0,Null);
Insert Into Students1(FirstName,SecondNAme,DOB,RegisterDate,Archived,ArchivedDate)
Values('Chris','Bike',16/04/1902,04/09/2017,1,getdate());
Insert Into Students1(FirstName,SecondNAme,DOB,RegisterDate,Archived,ArchivedDate)
Values('Sam','Bike',16/04/1999,04/09/2017,1,getdate());
Insert Into Students1(FirstName,SecondNAme,DOB,RegisterDate,Archived,ArchivedDate)
Values('Josh','Bike',16/04/1999,04/09/2017,1,getdate());
```

I want to do a simple select statement against this where I'm filtering on the either the `RegisterDate` or the `ArchivedDate`  depending on how my local variables are set up.

For instance, i will have the following local variables set;
`@FitlerRegisterDate`
`@FilterArchived` 
If either `@FilterREgisterDate` is set to 1 then the where clause will look at the `RegisterDate` column, but if the `@FilterArchived` is set to 1 then the where clause will look at the `ArchivedColumn` AND if they're both set to 1 then it should default to look at the `RegisterDate`

I've had a look at this for a while and cant see anything that stands out. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND` and `OR` clause to filter according to your variable values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Students1
WHERE  (    @FilterArchived     = 1 
        AND @FilterREgisterDate = 1 
        AND RegisterDate        = @dateToFilter )
  OR (   (    @FilterREgisterDate = 1 
          AND RegisterDate        = @dateToFilter )
      OR (    @FilterArchived = 1 
          AND ArchivedDate    = @dateToFilter ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM Students1
 WHERE @FilterREgisterDate = 1 AND RegisterDate = @RegisterDate
       OR @FilterREgisterDate <> 1 AND @FilterArchived = 1 AND ArchivedDate = @ArchivedDate
;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from dbo.Students1 where (@FilterArchived=1 AND @FilterREgisterDate=1) and registerdate='04/07/2017'

UNION 

select * from dbo.Students1 where (@FilterArchived!=1 AND @FilterREgisterDate=1) and registerdate='04/07/2017'

UNION

select * from dbo.Students1 where  (@FilterArchived=1 AND @FilterREgisterDate!=1) and archived=1
```